# Reducing space between two lines of navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar like this. http://www.bootply.com/COgUDvOM1e when I am trying to reduce the size the screen the navbar is collapsing. But I want to reduce the distance between lines.

I tried the below

```
.multiselect{
height:40px;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to reduce the `padding` of this element. Here's the code that would do it:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I would suggest using something like Chrome Dev Tool to inspect the elements and change the CSS within the page.